# LSTM and ros2 -- wait for image sequence before prediction -- callback issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, ros

I have implemented a LSTM deep learning model. I would like to use the trained model to predict autonomous driving commands. I use the LGSVL simulator to interact. During the autonomous driving part, I subscribe to 3 camera sensors and publish in a control command topic. Since they arrive at different rates, I use the [ros2 message filters](https://github.com/ros2/message_filters) module and its ApproximateTimeSynchronizer function to make a callback.

In the callback, I predict the commands by using the images. Since I use LSTM, I have made my input images as time series sequences according to the timesteps. For example, if the timesteps = 2, the model expects 2 sets of 3 camera images to predict. So that I use both t and t-1 frame images to predict t+1. However, in callback only one set is received.

So my question is how can I wait till I get 2(changes with timesteps defined) sets of images to make a callback? Can I store the images in a list, call them when it reaches appropriate length for prediction?

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Link to ros answers website -- https://answers.ros.org/question/355905/wait-for-images-before-prediction-time-steps-lstm-callback-issue/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. This can be done without ROS at all.
So,
I get the images. Introduce a ([FIFO dequeue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)) with maxlen as the timesteps of my definition. Then append to it at each callback. When the length of the queue is equal to the timesteps, call the predict method.